# minio python client, how to import Tags

Tags: python, minio

The Minio documentation for python shows the following code for creating tags to add to a file that is going to be stored on the Minio server.

```
tags = Tags(for_object=True)
tags["User"] = "jsmith"
```

Here is the source of the documentation https://docs.min.io/docs/python-client-api-reference.html

I have not found documentation anywhere for where Tags() comes from. Is this a Minio specific object? or is it related more generally to Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for the late answer, but there you go :

```py
from minio.commonconfig import Tags
```

As per https://github.com/minio/minio-py/blob/master/minio/commonconfig.py#L43